# Submit button in <thead>

Tags: html, forms, html-table, submit

I have an input submit button between the `<thead>` tags:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <thead>
          <th>TEXT</th>
          <td><input type="submit"></td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ...
            input text fields
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

But the post request does not contain the values of the input text fields.
If I put the submit button into `<tbody>` all works fine.

Is it not possible to use a submit button in  tag?
I need to put this button in the header because my table has a fixed header and I need my button being always visible.

Comment: The <table> quotes are inside the <form> quotes.

Comment: readability, inserted <form> tags

Comment: The Position of the submit is not limited, as long it's between the `<form>`tags. I think you're defining action, method and encoding in form tags? Are your parameters having `name=""` attributes? Please provide the full code, otherwise failures can't be found. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q31mgm40/

Answer (score 0):

Try using,  qoutes inside the  qouotes.

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <th>
      <form>
         <input type="submit"/>
     </th>
   </thead>
  </form>
</table>
```

Comment: try using, <form> inside <table>.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<form>` tag like this:

```
<form action="whatever.php" method="post">
<table>
<thead>
  <th>
    TEXT
  </th>
  <td>
    <input type="submit">
  </td>
</thead>
<tbody>
...
input text fields
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work just declare the form as

```
 <form .... 
  <table>
    ....
  </table>
 </form>
```

You are probably declaring form in tbody

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `<form action="file.php" method=""POST>` before the `<table>` tag.

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
  <table>
    <td>
    .
    .
    .
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
```